# Spring Batch from Gosu

Tags: spring, batch-processing, spring-batch, gosu

I would like to use Spring Batch as a library from Gosu. Do you have a comprehensive example on how to wire a Spring batch job in java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is new support for @Configuration in Spring Batch 2.2 snapshots, but I have no idea if that helps you in Gosu.  Example [here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/config/RetrySampleConfiguration.java).  If you need to create everything imperatively look at SimpleJob and SimpleStepFactoryBean.